# Set disabled attribute on referenced element

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using Element UI's `split-button` which renders an extra button which is not in the template. However, I can get access to the button in question by setting `ref="dropdown"` on the dropdown holding this button, and referring to it with `this.$refs.dropdown.$children`, and finally loop over the `$children` array. Now, I want to set the HTML attribute `disabled` on this button but I can't seem to find a straightforward way to do this in the Vue docs.

How do I go about setting attributes on references?

Comment: could you show how are you using that button in your template?

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`vm.$el`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-el) to get the underlying `Element`, and then use [`Element.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) to select the dropdown's caret button. With the button reference, you could then use [`Element.setAttribute('disabled', '')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) to add the `disabled` attribute, and [`Element.removeAttribute('disabled')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute) to remove it:

```
const btn = this.$refs.dropdown.$el.querySelector('.el-dropdown__caret-button');
if (enabled) {
  btn.removeAttribute('disabled');
} else {
  btn.setAttribute('disabled', '');
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/43rzq47l47)